# Topology of two letters: showing that two letters are homeomorphic (or not)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Hoe can i check if the letters T, K homemorphic or not?
Same about the letters E, W?
I guess that it can be shown by using connectedness and connected components but I have no idea how it can be applied.
Can you help me in that?

Comment: What font are these letters? Does the $W$ have [serifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) or not? That matters for the topology..

Comment: To show non-homeomorphism of certain letters, cut points and connectedness arguments are often a handy tool. To show homeomorphism show a continuous transformation.

Comment: They are Sans-serif font..they do not have serifs.@HennoBrandsma

Comment: So a $W$ is just a zig-zag line, i.e. homeomorphic to I etc.

Comment: For $E$ you can us Magdiragdag's argument: $E$ minus a point can be disconnected or connected (the latter only for 3 points) while I minus a point is only connected for 2 points...

Comment: $\cal E$ is a zigzag curve. As is $\scr E$. But $\sf E$ is not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila like I said, font matters. He probably wants `E` though.

Comment: That's right i want the letters without serifs..

Comment: I did not mange to use the homeomorphism explained below though it is necessary to use in my opinion (i would be thankful if someone can complete it) .. however i think that T, K are not homeomorphic , same for E ,W ..  can i say that in K there is a point that of we remove we get 4 components but in T there is not such a point , W is zigzag but E is not so they are not homeomorphic? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: True, $K$ has a point $p$ such that $K-p$ has $4$ components, and $T-p$ has at most 3 components whatever $p \in T$ we choose.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant here : E minus a point can be disconnected or connected (the latter only for 3 points) while I minus a point is only connected for 2 points.@HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \colon T \to K$ is a homeomorphism and $x \in T$, then $f \colon T \setminus \{x\} \to K \setminus \{f(x)\}$ is also a homeomorphism. Now, using your idea of connectedness and connected components, apply this to a very particular element of $T$ and count the number of connected components in $T \setminus \{x\}$ and in $K \setminus \{f(x)\}$. They should be equal, but for a very particular choice of $x$ they won't be.

A similar trick can be applied to $E$ and $W$.